# making change counter, cant divide coins

Tags: python

I have to design a program that when an amount of an item is entered,  asks the user for the amount paid,and then provides change in 20's 10's 5's 1s quarters, dimes, nickels, and pennies. I've spent hours trying to find the flaws in my code but I can't get it right. If someone could help me out that would be greatly appreciated!

I realize that my code is not very polished, but I just started and haven't learned too many techniques so far.
I have it all working until it hits dimes, then things go bad.

Here is my code at this point:

```
#assign variables#
import math
cost=float(input("Enter the price of the item: $"))
paid=float(input("Enter the amount paid: $"))
#calculations#
difference=round(paid,2)-round(cost,2)
change= round(difference,2)
#twentys#
remain20=float(change%20)
twent=float(change-remain20)
twent1=abs(float(twent)//20)
twent2=float(twent1*20)
sub1=float(change-float(twent2))
print(sub1,"sub1")
#tens

remain10=change%10
ten=sub1-remain10
ten1=ten//10
ten2=ten1*10
sub2=sub1-ten2
print(sub2,"sub2")
#fives

remain5=float(abs(change%5))
five=abs(float(sub2)-float(abs(remain5)))
five1=float(round(abs(five)//5))
five2=float(round(five*5))
sub3=abs(float(sub2)-abs(float(five2)))
print(sub3,"sub3")
#ones
remain1=change%1
one=abs(round(sub3)-abs(remain1))
one1=abs(round(one//1))
one2=abs(round(one*1))
sub4=abs(float(sub3))-abs(float(one2))
print(sub4,"sub4")
#quarters
remainq=change%(0.25)
remainq1=round(remainq,2)
q=abs(sub4)-(remainq1)
q1=abs(q//float(0.25))
q2=abs(q*0.25)
sub5=abs(float(sub4))-(float(q2))
print(sub5,"sub5")
#dimes

remaind=change%(0.10)
remaind1=round(remaind,2)
d=abs(round(sub5,2)-remaind1)
d1=abs(d//float(0.10))
d2=abs(d1*0.10)
sub6=abs(float(sub5))-abs(float(d2))
print(sub6,"sub6")
#nickles

remainn=change%(0.05)
remainn1=round(remainn,2)
n=abs(round(sub6,2)-abs(remainn1))
n1=abs(d//float(0.05))
n2=abs(d1*0.05)
sub7=float(abs(sub6)-float(n2))
print(sub7,"sub7")
#pennies

remainp=change%(0.01)
remainp1=round(remainp,2)
p=abs(round(sub7,2)-abs(remainp1))
p1=abs(d//float(0.01))
p2=abs(d1*0.01)
#outputs
print(round(twent1),str("Twenty dollar bills"))
print(round(ten1),str("Ten dollar bills"))
print(round(five1),str("Five dollar bills"))
print(round(one1),str("One dollar bills"))
print(round(q1),str("Quarters"))
print(int(d1),str("dimes"))
print(int(n1),str("nickles"))
print(int(p1),str("Pennies"))
```

Comment: Please elaborate on what "things go bad" means. Provide a [mcve] of your problem being more explicit about what is happening in your code that is not meeting your expectations.

Comment: What happens specifically?

Comment: It also might be easier to work with the values in your smallest unit (i.e. pennies).  So if the change to be given is $25.42 the value you start working with is 2542.  Use modulus with 2000 for $20's, 1000 for $10's ... 25 for quarters etc.  Will make the math easier and eliminate any issues you might encounter with floating point arithmetic.

Comment: as the immortal Edsger W. Dijkstra said, "two or more? Use a for!" In other words, if you ever find yourself doing the same thing (or nearly the same thing) over and over again, there's probably a way to refactor your code so that you can write just one block, and then loop over it as many times as you want.

Comment: In this case, that means you should probably create some data structure containing the _kinds_ of currencies you can use (five, ten, twenty dollar bills, quarters, nickles, dimes, etc), and how much money they each represent. Then you can simply loop over this list as calculate the amount of change needed from each value.

Comment: @idjaw @J F for example, 12.34 for cost and 13.00 for paid, my change would be 0.66. that goes through each section, subtracting whatever it can factor out on the way out. so at my sub 1--4 variables,  each sub variable = 0.66. at sub5 it turns into 0.535, but each sub variable is supposed to be whatever change is left to be sorted. so it schould be 16. my sub 6 value is 0.135 and my sub 7 value is -0.065

Comment: @Hamms: Yeah, that was my first thought, and why I posted [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39650893/364696). It takes less time to devise and write a better solution than it takes to physically type the poor one, and it's less likely to have subtle errors scattered around it; it's all right, or all wrong, and the errors are typically obvious.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend you to avoid using floating point numbers if the problem can be solved with integers. Think about it, in this particular problem you can convert all ammounts into pennies (multiplied by 100). That way the solution becomes straightforward, for instance:

```
def distribute(value):
    result = {
        2000: [0, "Twenty dollar"],
        1000: [0, "Ten dollar"],
        500: [0, "Five dollar"],
        100: [0, "One dollar"],
        25: [0, "Quarters"],
        10: [0, "dimes"],
        5: [0, "nickles"],
        1: [0, "Pennies"]
    }

    if value < 0:
        print("Not enough money... you need {0}$ more".format(abs(value)))
    elif value == 0:
        print("Thanks for buying in the shop!")
    else:
        pennies = value * 100

        for k in reversed(sorted(result.keys())):
            if k < pennies:
                result[k][0] = num_coins = int(pennies / k)
                print("{0} {1}{2}".format(
                    num_coins, result[k][1], " bills" if k >= 100 else ""))
                pennies -= num_coins * k

    return result

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        print("---------------------------")
        print(" Welcome to shopping 0.0.1 ")
        print("---------------------------")
        cost = int(input("Enter the price of the item: $"))
        paid = int(input("Enter the amount paid: $"))
        summary = distribute(paid - cost)
    except Exception as e:
        print("Something unexpected happened! {0}".format(e))
```

Comment: Don't use `float` for monetary calculations.

Comment: ShadowRange Indeed, your comment is implied in my answer though, quoting: `I'd recommend you to avoid using floating point numbers if the problem can be solved with integers`

Comment: Thanks a bunch for helping me out. I'll definitely use the whole numbers instead of float. I just started my programming class a few weeks ago so I haven't delved too deep into many of the functions used in your code so I have to work around your code a little bit, but its definetly a step in the right direction so thank you!

Comment: @Hirschzd01 No worries, also consider the comments mentioned on your question, they are also giving valuable points ;)

Comment: I will for sure! @BPL

Comment: By the by, surely the test should be for `value < 0`? If you paid exactly what the item cost, that's not an error. On a minor improvement note, `reversed(sorted(result.keys()))` could be simplified to `sorted(result, reverse=True)`; `dict`s are already iterables of their keys, and `sorted` can sort in reverse order directly at zero extra cost to save the `reversed` wrapping.

Comment: @ShadowRanger You're absolutely right, thanks, edited

Comment: Sorry, still some flaws (only because you added more code). You're prompting for dollar prices, which means you won't accept `"5.26"` as an input. You need to read as `float` (or `decimal.Decimal`, but let's avoid that for what's clearly an introductory exercise), then multiply, then `round` to `int` pennies.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Hehe, sure, I'll stop it here at 0.0.1 though. If I start refactoring I'm afraid I'll start adding more and more features and not sure whether that'll be very useful for the OP, who's started a programming class only few weeks ago, I think this is more than good enough for him to digest. Thanks for your points though ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your primary problem is that monetary calculations (and remainder operations) don't work so well with `float`. Convert to an `int` number of pennies up front, and most sources of error disappear (as long as you round properly).

You can also simplify the code a lot. Right now, every denomination is its own special case, even though the work is fundamentally the same for all of them aside from the string name and the unit. Generalize the code, and you can simplify it all down to a simple loop with a couple (constant, top-level) `tuple`s defining the parts that actually change:

```
# These are the only thing that differ as you go, so just list them explicitly
denominations = ('Twenty dollar bills', 'Ten dollar bills', 'Five dollar bills', 'One dollar bills', 'quarters', 'dimes', 'nickels', 'pennies')
divisors = (2000, 1000, 500, 100, 25, 10, 5, 1)

def make_change(paid, cost):
    '''paid and cost should be floats with up to two decimal places of precision'''
    # Calculate the difference in price, then convert to an int penny count
    # so we can use accurate math
    change = round((paid - cost) * 100)  # Wrap round in int constructor on Py2

    # Not necessary if inputs are trusted, but good form
    if change < 0: raise ValueError("Underpaid!")

    # Each loop replaces a special case from your code by swapping in the
    # string and divisor for that round
    for denom, div in zip(denominations, divisors):
        numdenom, change = divmod(change, div)
        # Conditional print; weird to say "0 fives", "0 ones" over and over
        # You can print unconditionally if you prefer
        if numdenom:
            print(numdenom, denom)
```

That's it. The whole of the calculation is (ignoring comments and blank lines) two constant definitions and seven lines of actual code.

Answer (score -1):

```
import math

def to_pennies(amt):
  return int(math.floor(amt * 100))

def make_change(amt):
  pennies = to_pennies(amt)
  twenties = pennies % 2000
  pennies -= twenties * 2000
  fives = pennies % 500
  pennies -= fives * 500
  ...  # Fill in the rest
  nickels = pennies % 5
  pennies -= nickels * 5
  return dict(
    twenties=twenties,
    fives=fives,
    ... # fill in the rest
    nickels=nickels,
    pennies=pennies)
```

Comment: You want `round`, not `math.floor` for `to_pennies`; floating point imprecision means you might be a tiny bit below the logical result of multiplying by 100. For example, on my Python 3.5 install (which should mirror most [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) float compliant machines), if `amt` is `0.29`, `amt * 100` equals `28.999999999999996`, which `math.floor` truncates to `28`. Also, on Python 3, `round` with no second argument produces `int` directly, so wrapping in `int` can be skipped too (sadly, this is not the case on Py2, where `round` returns `float`).

Comment: Also, your math is backwards. The number of 20s should be `pennies // 2000`, not `pennies % 2000`. Or you could make use of `divmod` to half the number of lines of code needed: `twenties, pennies = divmod(pennies, 2000)` replaces (and corrects) the line for `twenties` and its following line.